# Paho-mqtt client on Django

Tags: python, django, mqtt

Good morning everyone

I need a guide on how to configure an mqtt subscriber in a Django app and thus receive messages from CloudMQTT. I try to make a prototype IoT of low energy consumption, for the measurement of temperature and humidity.

If someone can refer me to a project with which I can be guided, it would be very helpful.

Comment: What do you plan to do with a message you are receiving asynchronously in a synchronous WSGI application?

Comment: I want to consume the message data generated by the sensor synchronously or as much as possible in real time. Finally able to view it from a URL in a Django application. I do not know how to distribute the functions of paho-mqtt in the Django-app to achieve the goal.

Honestly I am not very experienced, but I am very willing to learn and receive suggestions.

Thanks for the prompt response